# How to configure NestJS TypeOrm with URI instead of host, port, username and password fields?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, nestjs, typeorm

The Heroku Postgres addon provides DB connection details as `postgres://user:pw@host:port` in the `DATABASE_URL` env var.

I'm wondering how to configure a NestJS app using TypeOrm, because all the examples look like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: '...',
        port: 5432,
        username: '...',
        password: '...',
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `url` option:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
}),
```

You can also do this locally, for example, on Docker using the `postgres` image your connection looks like this:

```
postgres://postgres:@<db_service_name>:5432
```

Comment: you saved my time as well. i wrote `mysql://~~` text using mysql. thanks

Comment: options like synchronize how to paass that?

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem with `postgres://` protocol and I had change to `postgresql://` to have database connection fully working.